# Path Algorithm: How to tell whether a path from A to B to A on a grid goes around anything?

Tags: algorithm, path, graph-algorithm

I need to figure out if the path from A to B and back to A goes around anything.

Example:
The path here is APPPPPPBA. It goes around an X, so the result is TRUE.

```
XXXXXXXX
XPPPXXXX
XBXPXXXX
XAPPXXXX
XXXXXXXX
```

The path here is APPPPPPPBA. It doesn't go around any X's, so the result is FALSE.

```
XXXXXXXX
XPPPXXXX
XBPPXXXX
XAPPXXXX
XXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a border of additional `X` tiles around the grid. Do a [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) starting from one of these tiles to mark tiles as "surrounding the path". If, afterwards, all tiles are either flood filled or part of the path, the path hasn't encircled anything. (The border is needed to handle the situation where the path cuts the grid in two. Alternatively, you can start the flood fill at each edge tile.)